# Logic behind balancing an unbalanced tree (Bayes theorem)

Tags: probability, trees, bayes-theorem

I found an explanation for Bayes theorem in this site,
https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-statistics/probability-ap/stats-conditional-probability/v/bayes-theorem-visualized . Here, the person takes an example of a biased coin (along with 2 other fair coins). So when you draw a tree, the leaf nodes of the biased coin would contain 3 events ( other nodes with 2 events (leaf nodes)), and he balances the tree by taking the lcm. I got a confused at this part. I'm struggling to understand the logic behind balancing an unbalanced tree. I'd appreciate if someone could help. Thanks .